# how to read the data from the JSP in a MXML through actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

We are collecting the data at run time in Collection object in JSP page. We want to read this data from the JSP in a MXML through actionscript.
pls share the sample if you have.

thanks,
Sudarshan

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadData():void
{
  var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("page.jsp");
  ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
  ldr.load(request);
}
private function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var ldr:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
  trace(ldr.data);//traces the loaded string
  //if the data is xml
  /*
  var myxml:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
  trace(myxml.toXMLString());
  */
  //update: answer to the comment:
  //If the input string just lacks a root tag from being valid xml, 
  //you can introduce a dummy root tag.
  var myxml:XML = new XML("<root>" + ldr.data + "</root>");
  trace(myxml.data.toString());  //Hello
  trace(myxml.value.toString()); //Hi
}
```

page.jsp should serialize the collection to appropriate format (xml/json/whatever) and return it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i have one more problem here.In my JSP i have XML tag but i am unable to get value .
for example.
my jsp is like.

<data>Hello</data>
<value>Hi</value>

So if i want to get the value of data or value how can i get.

from above example what you gave i am getting following error.

TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
pls help..

Comment: @user the string passed from jsp should be a valid xml - your string isn't valid xml - there's no root tag. Add the root tags at either jsp or flash end.

Comment: @Amarghosh .. I have already added the root tag. if you can give one example may be that may help. But i have one more doubt if i write file name as .jsp but asking for XML wont it crate the above error?

Comment: @user What do you get for `trace(ldr.data);`? No, the jsp file should create an xml string and return it - post your jsp code

Comment: i am getting full file content. My JSP is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Start>
<test>
<data>A</data>


</test>
<test>
<data>B</data>

</test>
</Start>

Comment: That's not your jsp, that's just plain xml; I thought you wanted to read a serialized Collection from jsp. For this one you can just do `var myxml:XML = new XML(ldr.data); trace(myxml.test.data[0], myxml.test.data[1]);` - and you can use `.xml` extension for the file

Comment: Still its in development stage so i havent wrote full code. I need to get the value from servlet at run time and put this value in the script.